# How to update a LaTeX package?

Tags: packages, texlive, tkz-euclide, update

I have the Tex Live 2017 in Trisquel, I installed from the compact disc.

I need to update the tkz-euclide package, for that I entered the tlmgr window:

[image]

When I order the update, I get this result:

```
Executing action update tkz-euclide
tlmgr: package repository /usr/local/texlive/2017 (not verified: unknown)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2017/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
tlmgr: Your installation is set up to look on the disk for updates.
To install from the Internet for this one time only, run:
  tlmgr -repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet ACTION ARG...
where ACTION is install, update, etc.; see tlmgr -help if needed.

To change the default for all future updates, run:
  tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
Completed.
```

When I execute that command in my shell, I get this message:

```
tlmgr: no action given; try --help if you need it.
```

I do not know what else to do.

Comment: Afaik, you cannot update a package of an outdated distribution.

Comment: if you want to update the package to a version that was already in tl2017 you can use the historic repository, if you want a newer version you will have to do the update manually. The alternative is to install texlive 2020.

Comment: I see, I will install texlive 2020. Thanks.